# LTSpice, setting multiple PWL FILE="..." Voltage sources

Tags: ltspice

I am trying to design a circuit for a three phase power generator with an unusual waveform, and the first step is to combine each of the component phases into a single signal. When I set one of the voltage sources (say V3 for example) to a PWL file which models the waveform, all the other voltage sources automatically change their input PWL file path to the file path I just typed (Entering a file path for V3 will change the file paths of V1 and V2 to V3's file path). Is there a way to simulate multiple custom wave forms?

[image: full bridge rectifier]

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, that doesn't happen. Anyway, this sort of question is better suited for the [LTspice group](http://groups.io/g/LTspice/).